# Flexibly creating logical statements from Vectors with text elements

Tags: r, shiny

I'm probably going about this in a silly way but bear with me. I'm using `selectizeInput` in `shiny` so users can select multiple categories. Those selections are used to subset a dataframe. After trying `match` and `pmatch` and `%in%`  to look for patterns in text, I decided to use `grep`. Its able to find the proper row when a project has multiple categories. **However**, the pattern paramter can't have a length greater than 1. The workaround? Add `|` (or operator) between elements in the pattern. I need help coming up with a process for inserting `|` between elements of a vector so I can use `grep` to subset dataframes when `length(input$Category)>1`.

## Example

```
df <- data.frame(title = 1:5, category = c("ab", "bcd", "efg","ab,bcd","efg"))
```

#### selected category

```
cate <- c("bcd")
df[grep(cate,x = df$category),]
```

### Works great!

*But*, if someone were to select more than one category, `grep` only uses the first element in the pattern:

```
cate <- c("bcd","efg")
df[grep(cate,x = df$category),]
```

#### failure

#### UNLESS we add an `|` between the categories selected

```
cate <- c("bcd|efg")
df[grep(cate,x = df$category),]
```

#### success

I cannot figure out how to programmatically add the `|` between elements of cate without making a giant mess with `if` statements.

```
 if(length(cate)== 1){
    df[grep(cate,x = df$category),])
    } else {
    if(length(cate) == 2){
      cate2 <- paste(cate[[1]],"|",cate[[2]], sep = "")
      df[grep(cate2,x = df$category),]
    } else {...
```

There must be some way to generate the pattern:

```
paste(cate[[1]],"|",cate[[2]],...,"|",cate[[n]], sep = "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure on what you're doing and thus can't point you to the "better" solution, but for your purposes I'm pretty sure something along the lines of this will do:

```
cate <- character()
cate[1] <- c("ab")
cate[2] <- c("efg")
cate[3] <- c("ab")

do.call(what = paste, c(list(cate), collapse = "|"))
```

Comment: Looks like you have followed along well enough. Let me double to check that your answer works and then I will approve it.